# How do I replace " " with "_"?

Tags: c++, string

So I have an input string of characters. If the string contain spaces or is less than 15 characters long I have to replace the empty spaces with an underscore("_").

This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string spaces(int i){
        char arr[i];
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
         arr[j]='_';
        }
        string space(arr);
        return space;
} 

int main(){
        string str = "USERNAME12034";
        if(str.size() < 15){
        // get size of username;
        int size = 15-str.size();
        str = str.append(spaces(size));
        }
        cout << str << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it, this is the output:

```
 USERNAME12034__�O�
```

How do I get rid of those characters at the end?

Comment: Use `std::replace`.

Comment: The problem is badly worded: the description says "pad to 15 characters", but the title is "replace spaces with underscores".

Comment: Thanks Chris, I didn't know there was a replace function I could've used so that takes care of replacing empty spaces. However, how do I append a certain number of empty spaces if the username is less than 15 characters long?

Comment: There's an `append` overload that takes a character and how many.

Answer (score 2):

The `string::string(char *)` constructor expects a null-terminated string.  `arr` is not null-terminated, so the constructor walks off the end of the array and keeps appending random garbage from memory until it finds a byte with the value '0'.

If you want to use this method to pad the string with underscores, you should make `arr` one character larger than the number of underscores needed, and set that last spot to the value `'\0'`.

Comment: You probably also need to explain for the OP what exactly a _'null-terminated string'_ means.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use one of the append functions [`std::basic_string::append`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append).

The [`std::string::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) can be used inside a loop to add underscores until the length is 15 (or whatever limit has to be enforced).

Similarly, use the [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) function to replace all user entered spaces with an underscore.  The

```
string spaces (int i)
```

function is no longer needed (solving the non-terminated array problem Mark has listed).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by using the following:

```
string addUnderscore(string text, int size){
   text = text.append(size, ' ');
   for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
   {
      if(text[i] == ' ')
      text[i] = '_';
   }
   return text;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The task can be done in two steps. At first you should replace all spaces with undescores in the original string. For example

```
std::replace( str.begin(), str.end(), ' ', '_' );
```

And after that you should check whether the size of the string is less than 15 and if so then append the string with underscores

```
if ( str.size() < 15 ) str.resize( 15, '_' );
```

So combining these two statements you will get

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

//...

std::replace( str.begin(), str.end(), ' ', '_' );
if ( str.size() < 15 ) str.resize( 15, '_' );
```

As for your function then it is wrong. First of all it is not C++ compliant. In C++ there is no variable length arrays. So you may not write

```
string spaces(int i){
        char arr[i];
        //...
}
```

Also array arr is not null terminated. So call of constructor `string space(arr);` has undefined behaviour.

The function could look the following way

```
void format( std::string &str )
{
    std::replace( str.begin(), str.end(), ' ', '_' );
    if ( str.size() < 15 ) str.resize( 15, '_' );
}
```